# Multidimensional lists in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

My question is about multidimensional lists in VB. Is it common to use such things, for example `list As List(Of List(Of List(Of Integer)))`?

And what are the use cases in general for List, ArrayList, and Array in VB?

Comment: If you give us more information about your data structure we can help . If you need a key=value pair you use a dictionary. If you have multiple lists you can do a collection of lists or a list of lists. If it's more complex you can make your own object as a collection type. See this section;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` should not be used. It's still around for backwards compatibility with code from pre-.Net 2.0 (circa 2005) projects, before generics were available, as well (IIRC) as some PowerShell interop and the WinForms `My.Settings` interface. I think even the PowerShell interop is being done with `List<PSObject>` now, and ArrayList doesn't really serve any other purpose anymore.

Arrays should only be used when the size of the data really is fixed at creation.

For just about everything else use a `List(Of T)` or similar appropriate collection type.

However, `List(Of List(Of List(Of Integer)))` would be unusual. This almost always indicates the need for a Tuple, Class, or other advanced collection type. If you tell us what you're trying to do, we can help you with a more-appropriate collection type.

Speaking of advanced collections, don't ignore `Dictionary(Of K,V)`, `HashSet(Of T)`, and the many other collections provided for you by .Net.

I'll add that .Net also has the concept of an `IEnumerable`, which is a basic interface that can stand in for many different collection types. Very often you should define arguments and return types to use `IEnumerable(Of T)` (and rarely `IList(Of T)` or `ICollection(Of T)`), regardless of what you actually do in the method. This will allow you to, say, pass a List or an array to the same method, and sets you up to work with iterators and streaming data, which can be a HUGE memory and performance boost.

Finally, I have some notes about arrays. A **real** array, in the formal computer-science sense, refers to a fixed block of contiguous memory. Many modern platforms (and javascript) provide something more like .Net's `List(Of T)` or even `Dictionary(Of K,V)`, in order to provide features like `Add()`, `Remove()`, associative lookups, and more. They then *call it* an array, when in fact you might not have contiguous memory at all.

Unlike these other platforms, .Net still uses real arrays. This allows it to more easily provide interop with things like lower-level operating system APIs, which often require raw array buffers, where other platforms might struggle. It also allows for certain high-performance code that is not possible if you can't know the memory is contiguous. .Net does this without sacrificing the features mentioned above by also providing collections like `List(Of T)`. You just need to know what you're actually working with.